# Is there online data on asteroid axial tilts?

Tags: orbit, rotation, asteroids

I am hoping to find axial tilts for asteroids and also their spring and fall equinox. Some of the asteroids I'm interested in are:
4 Vesta, 1 Ceres, 24 Themis, 65 Cybele, 153 Hilda, 624 Hektor

Answer (score 1):

From this article, http://hubblesite.org/pubinfo/pdf/2010/33/pdf.pdf, here's the rotation axis for 4 Vesta: RA=307.5°±3.1°, Dec=43.1°±1.2°. Update, per TildalWave's comment: [RA=305.8°±3.1°, Dec=41.4°±1.5°](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103510003726)

[Rotational motion of Ceres](http://yly-mac.gps.caltech.edu/A_DPS/dps%202011%20/a_dps%202011%20program%20+%20abstracts/pdf/EPSC-DPS2011-829.pdf).

An old article (1986): Magnusson, P., *Distribution of spin axes and senses of rotation for 20 large asteroids*, Icarus 68:1 1-39 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0019103586900722